# read huge Json file in R stream_in or another option

Tags: json, r, parsing, chunks, jsonlite

I have 2 gb Json file which requires to read in R,I have tried to parse using stream_in function following this code ,

```
h <- function(x){input <<-x}
dat <- llply(as.list("cookie.JSON"),function(x) stream_in(file("cookie.JSON"),pagesize = 5000,handler = h))
```

each time i stop the execution give a name input to data frame,actually which is not logical and wasting time.
Someone had an experiment breaking down Jsonfile ?

Comment: Can you share the json @akakiyakakiyevic

Comment: 2 mb isn't big enough to warrant a streaming solution. Try just using `jsonlite::fromJSON`.

Comment: that is gb,each execution is crashed and pc is frozen,i wanna use stream_in each parse has saved as a data frame instead of executing code and stop save process.

Comment: @taran http://dosya.co/0ndgcgizyp02/datamining_20171130-000000_24.json.html

Comment: @Taran following links,can you pls take a look which is nested and hard into a data frame in r